Create regex for price
I need to replace my input value if count of digits after . more then 2 and replace "," to "." if user input it.
For example: user input 6554,43553 input should contain 6554.43
I tried create regex, but every time something went wrong

What language or tool are you using?  Could you have multiple commas as in the case of a large number?  Could your string contain no commas at all? Could the string already have dots in them? Are you sure you don't want to round the digits after the decimal point?

If you need just a substitution regex:
(\d+)([.,])(\d{0,2})(\d*)
and substitution $1.$3
JavaScript code will be:
'6554,43553'.replace(/(\d+)([.,])(\d{0,2})(\d*)/, '$1.$3') // "6554.43"
'6554,43'.replace(/(\d+)([.,])(\d{0,2})(\d*)/, '$1.$3') // "6554.43"
'6554,4'.replace(/(\d+)([.,])(\d{0,2})(\d*)/, '$1.$3') // "6554.4"
'6554,'.replace(/(\d+)([.,])(\d{0,2})(\d*)/, '$1.$3') // "6554."
'6554'.replace(/(\d+)([.,])(\d{0,2})(\d*)/, '$1.$3') // "6554"

But please note it does not correctly round the user's price.
If you are using any specific language you should first replace coma to dot and then round it.
i.e. JavaScript
parseFloat('6554,43553'.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2) // "6554.44"


You can use the following regular expression to match the pattern you described:
^(\d+)(,\d{1,2})?\d*$

Explanation:

^: Start of the line.
(\d+): Matches one or more digits before the
decimal point and captures them in a group.
(,\d{1,2})?: Matches an optional comma followed by 1 to 2 digits after the decimal point.
\d*: Matches any additional digits after the decimal point.
$: End of
the line.

To perform the replacement, you can use this regular expression along with your programming language's string manipulation functions. If the match is found, you can replace the comma with a dot and truncate any extra digits after the second decimal place.
